# Viewing area of window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, null, xna

Hi i need find out size of viewing area of my game window. I found this code :

```
int height = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
```

but return this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can you anyone help me how solve this problem ? Thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that `GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height` is null then, not inited yet. `GraphicsDevice` is inside `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics` namespace.

if you are inheriting from game class try with:

```
this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

or with

```
this.Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

where are you trying to populate those integers?

**added example**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public int screenWidth;
    public int screenHeight;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height looks like it could be a class or something due to its capitalization, but the biggest clue is the part in the error where it says object reference. The .Height at the end gets the Height **object** of Viewport. You need to access a property/member variable of the object (probably named height; the easiest way to find it would be code completion) to assign it to a variable.